# Поиск соответствий в файле со списком

Tags: python, поиск, файлы

Есть файл .txt. В нем должен быть список с двумя столбцами: в первом - mac адреса, во втором - имена компьютеров. С помощью python-скрипта необходимо получить mac адрес машины, на которой был запущен скрипт и определить какому имени компьютера он соответствует.

Также, подскажите, пожалуйста, как следует организовать этот список в файле?

Comment: Забыл упомянуть, что машины все на ubuntu, если это имеет значение

Comment: Ну это совсем тривиальная задача, даже хоть маломальски грамотный не специалист пишущий на Python должен уметь пользоваться стандартной либой...

Comment: К сожалению, в Python-е я совсем новичок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы по маку машины, на которой запущен скрипт, хотите определить имя машины?

Для получения мака можно воспользоваться библиотекой netifaces https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces

Мак интерфейса:

```
import netifaces
netifces.ifaddress('eth0')[netifaces.AF_LINK]['addr']
```

Имя хоста:

```
import socket
socket.gethostname()
```

Если нужно работать именно со списком маков из файла то:

```
macs_hosts_file = open('macs_hosts.txt', 'r')
mymac='01:23:45:67:89:AB'

mac_host_dict = {}
for line in macs_hosts_file:
    mac, hostname = line.split(' ')
    mac_host_dict[mac] = hostname

if mymac in mac_host_dict:
    print 'MAC is: %s\nHostname is: %s' % (mymac, mac_host_dict[mac])
```

Comment: Верно. Это необходимо для реализации определенной задумки, которую объяснять не обязательно

Comment: Спасибо.
А что с реализацией самого поиска соответствий в файле ?